# Connect PHP to database hosted within PhpStorm via SSH Tunnel

Tags: phpstorm

I used [this tutorial](http://deadkitteninaframe.com/wordpress/ssh-tunnel-jdbc-in-phpstorm/) to connect to a remote MySQL database via SSH tunnel within PhpStorm. When I try to connect to this via PHP, the database is not found.

The URL that PhpStorm gives me is `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName`

How can I connect to this database via PHP script? (running via the default built-in php server in PhpStorm).

Comment: *"Connect PHP to database hosted within PhpStorm"* PhpStorm does not host any databases. But generally speaking -- you may need to create such SSH tunnel first (outside of IDE, of course) so it's available for your whole system/OS and then run your PHP script. From PHP side it will be as usual (as if it's a standard local/remote connection).

Comment: Here you can check how to setup such SSH tunnel: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel#RemotedebugginginPhpStormviaSSHtunnel-2.SetupanSSHtunneltotheremotemachine (you will have to adjust it for MySQL ports .. as those examples are for PHP debugging).

Comment: @LazyOne I did it the way you recommended, which worked fine. I was just curious to see if it was possible to externalize the connection from PhpStorm. Thank you. I can choose it as a best answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Connect PHP to database hosted within PhpStorm"

First of all -- PhpStorm does not host any databases (especially MySQL) -- it only can connect to them (it acts like built-in DB client/viewer/editor).

It uses own SSH tunnel (interacts with it directly in the code -- so DB connection is aware of such possibility).

---

Generally speaking -- for your PHP code to be able to connect to a remote database via SSH tunnel .. you should either:

- establish such SSH connection in your code and then use it internally (not sure at all if PHP can do that, especially if DB-related routines can use it -- most likely not)..
- or establish SSH tunnel outside as OS level so it's available to all processes. This way it will be transparent to your code (it will not be aware of tunnel thinking that it connects to local/remote DB in a "natural" way).

So the 2nd option is the way to go.

[Here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel#RemotedebugginginPhpStormviaSSHtunnel-2.SetupanSSHtunneltotheremotemachine) you can check how to setup such SSH tunnel -- it has examples fr=or Linux/Mac and Windows as well (you will have to adjust it for MySQL ports .. as those examples are for PHP debugging).